# Transform Soap message to soap message use xslt in Mule

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, mule

I want transform soap message to soap message use xslt in mule

I not get element to soap message 1 to soap message 2

**1. I have soap**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
<ns:topic xmlns:ns="http://wso2.org/ns/2009/09/eventing/notify">polling_Topic</ns:topic>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>

<data-services-event>

<service-name>pollingService</service-name>
<query-id>pollingQuery</query-id>
<time>Wed May 24 10:01:18 ICT 2017</time>

<content>
<Students xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/eventing_sample">
<student>

<count>25</count>
<id>25</id>
<Name>Tran Anh</Name>
<Contact>Dong Thap</Contact>
<regdatetime>2017-05-23T14:41:35.000+07:00</regdatetime>

</student>
</Students>
</content>

</data-services-event>

</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**this is transform.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>         
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>          
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"                                         xmlns:dat="http://dataservice.ws.wso2.org">
                      <soapenv:Header/>
                      <soapenv:Body>
                         <dat:insertPerson>
                            <!--Optional:--><dat:name><xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/data-services-event/content/Students/student/Name" /></dat:name>
                            <!--Optional:--><dat:contact><xsl:value-of select="data-services-event/content/Students/student/Contact/text()" /></dat:contact>

                         </dat:insertPerson>
                      </soapenv:Body>
             </soapenv:Envelope>    
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I get result:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:dat="http://dataservice.ws.wso2.org"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dat:insertPerson>
         <dat:name/>
         <dat:contact/>         
      </dat:insertPerson>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**I not get element:  Name and Contact**

How to do it

Comment: Does your input really have two `soap:Envelope/soap:Body` nested in each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why you don't get the expected values. One is that your paths are missing some location steps. The other is that the `Students` element and its descendants are in a namespace, and you need to use a prefix bound to the same namespace in order to select them.

Here's your stylesheet with some modifications:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:dat="http://dataservice.ws.wso2.org"
xmlns:stu="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/eventing_sample"
exclude-result-prefixes="stu">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>          

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope >
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <dat:insertPerson>
                <dat:name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/data-services-event/content/stu:Students/stu:student/stu:Name" />
                </dat:name>
                <dat:contact>
                    <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/data-services-event/content/stu:Students/stu:student/stu:Contact" />
                </dat:contact>
            </dat:insertPerson>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It work, get elements, thank michael.hor257k, thank you verry much !